# user upstart job in ~/.init/ is not found

Tags: 12.04, upstart, services

Running 12.04, I have the following upstart job in `~/.init/`:

```
# myjob

start on net-device-up
stop on [!12345]

script

echo ">> hello from user script" >> ~/tmp/upstart.log

end script
```

After rebooting my machine

```
service myjob start
# => myjob: unrecognised service
```

`initctl` does list the job, but running it without sudo throws an error:

```
initctl start myjob
# => initctl: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.100" (uid=1000 pid=13349 comm="initctl start thunderbird ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

I would expect to be able to start the job using `service` or `initctl` without using `sudo`. What have I misunderstood?

Thanks

Comment: How did you enable User Jobs? The documentation in the answer you accepted is incomplete, at best...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few points:

1. User jobs are not enabled by default in Ubuntu. See:

   - http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#user-job
   - http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#enabling
2. You never need to reboot after creating any type of Upstart job—they are automatically detected by Upstart (using inotify).
3. The `service` command is not part of Upstart—it is the SystemV tool to manipulate SysV jobs. However, Upstart provides SystemV compatibility such that Upstart system jobs can also be manipulated via `service` (for convenience). The Upstart equivalent commands are `start`, `stop` and, `restart`.
4. For user jobs, you must use `start`, `stop` and, `restart` (or the `initctl` equivalents).

Finally, note that user jobs are very basic currently. We plan to enhance them significantly for 12.10 but for now be aware that:

- Upstart will run *all* user jobs using `/bin/sh -e` regardless of which shell you use by default. That `-e` is also very important (`man sh` for details).
- Upstart will only set a minimal set of variables in the user job environment. Hence, you should probably set variables like `HOME` like this:

  `env HOME=/home/james`

See:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#env
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#export
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#debugging-a-script-which-appears-to-be-behaving-oddly

Comment: Thanks James, I thought I'd read that user jobs were enabled in Precise. Thanks for clearing up my confusion.

Comment: How would I auto-start a user job on Ubuntu 12.04? I've found a [tutorial](http://bradleyayers.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/enabling-upstart-user-jobs-to-start-at.html), which worked for me on Ubuntu 11.10, but not on Ubuntu 12.04. Any ideas?

Comment: Strange, the documentation doesn't seem to mention _how_ to enable user jobs, it only mentions the config file, and that the administrator must do it. Aren't we all administrators?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that, you can't overload existing policies either e.g. user=...,..... Take the second block, copy/paste and change the user= to suit. You can also do groups per the DTD.

Comment: @ppetraki could you please post an answer clearly outlining the changes to be made to `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/Upstart.conf`? It's baffling how vague and incomplete the documentation on such a critical system utility is.

Comment: @namoul, I'll patch the actual docs instead. https://code.launchpad.net/upstart-cookbook

Comment: The referred-to `Upstart.conf` file can be found [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~upstart-devel/upstart/trunk/view/head:/dbus/Upstart.conf).

Comment: @denisw Is this a drop-in replacement that just enables user jobs? The Upstart.conf file bundled with ubuntu 12.04 server is a lot bigger

Comment: Following Upstart.conf configuration https://gist.github.com/bradleyayers/1660182 worked for me - Ubuntu 12.04, jobs in ~/.init, no restart after saving Upstart.conf needed.