# How to enable user jobs in Upstart

Tags: 12.04, users, upstart

I'm trying to allow non-privileged users to run upstart jobs from their `$HOME/.init` directory.

Upstart cookbook mentions that you must [enable this](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#enabling), but doesn't mention how to do it. The frustration can be summarised by [@ropez's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153064/user-upstart-job-in-init-is-not-found#comment254287_153126):

> the documentation doesn't seem to mention *how* to enable user jobs, it only mentions the config file, and that the administrator must do it

I'm still getting this error when I try to `start` a job as a non-privileged user:

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.70"
```

The closest I found so far is a gist of [someone's patched Upstart.conf](https://gist.github.com/bradleyayers/1660182), but it seems a lot shorter than the one I see in Ubuntu 12.04 that I'm using.

Is there a canonical, well-defined way of doing this?

P.S. I am aware of [related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153064/user-upstart-job-in-init-is-not-found) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229809/allow-non-sudo-group-to-control-upstart-job). However, none of their answers actually show how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for Upstart 1.5 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Open the upstart config:

```
sudo vim /etc/dbus-1/system.d/Upstart.conf
```

Comment out the `default` policy, i.e.

```
<policy context="default">
    ...
</policy>
```

and paste the block from [this patch](https://gist.github.com/bradleyayers/1660182):

```
<!--
Allow any user to invoke all of the methods on Upstart, its jobs
or their instances, and to get and set properties - since Upstart
isolates commands by user.
 -->
<policy context="default">
    <allow send_destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
        send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" />
    <allow send_destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
        send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" />
    <allow send_destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
        send_interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6" />
    <allow send_destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
        send_interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" />
    <allow send_destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
        send_interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Instance" />
</policy>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "patched" Upstart configuration you link to is the same as the Upstart configuration that was shipped with [Upstart 1.3](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~upstart-devel/upstart/trunk/view/1301/dbus/Upstart.conf) (from [cannot get upstart to run user job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219760/cannot-get-upstart-to-run-user-job)), so I'd say that is the simplest way to enable user jobs.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 ships with Upstart 1.5 by default, and the config seems to be different (without user jobs enabled).